# Помогите разобраться variadic templates

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Покажите пожалуйста простой пример с variadic templates. Хотелось бы следующее

(Добавил деструктор)

```
class IAnimal{
public:
   virtual ~IAnimal() {}
   virtual void fuu() = 0;
};

class Animal : public IAnimal{
public:
   Animal(){}
   void fuu(){}
};

template<class... anyClass>
class Farm{
public:
    Farm(anyClass... arg){
    //Как поместить список аргументов конструктора в вектор.
}
private:
std::vector<IAnimal*> vec;
};

int main(){

    IAnimal* dog = new Animal();
    IAnimal* cat = new Animal();

    Farm<IAnimal*, IAnimal*> obj(dog,cat);

    delete cat; 
    delete dog; 
}
```

Или я не понимаю чего то важного.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33868486/4928642

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, мне кажется, раз тип точно задан - к чему возня с шаблонами?

```
class IAnimal{
public:
    virtual void fuu() = 0;
};

class Animal : public IAnimal{
public:
    Animal(){}
    void fuu(){}
};

class Farm
{
public:
    Farm(initializer_list<IAnimal*> l):vec(l.begin(),l.end())
    {
    }
private:
    std::vector<IAnimal*> vec;
};

int main(){

    IAnimal* dog = new Animal();
    IAnimal* cat = new Animal();

    Farm obj {dog,cat};
}
```

См. https://ideone.com/7cPzVB

Comment: Ну может ему надо именно с шаблонами разобраться?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87197/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-harry).

Comment: Суть была в том, чтобы иметь возможность передавать туда указатели на разные типы, не унаследованные от интерфейса. Но не придумал, как положить их в вектор, создал интерфейс. Возможно ли такое без интерфейса?

Comment: Но все равно разнородные указатели в вектор не спрятать. Тогда нужен, скажем, tuple...

Answer (score 3):

Если вы хотите идти именно по этому пути, то просто

```
Farm(anyClass... arg) : vec{ arg... } {}
```

и все. Или, для вашего случая, возможно лучше

```
Farm(anyClass *... arg) : vec{ arg... } {}
```

При этом в C++17 ваш класс получит неявный deduction guide, который позволит вам объявлять объекты как

```
Farm obj(dog, cat);
```

т.е. без явного указания шаблонных аргументов.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7acbb9e506f8e66

Однако я не вижу необходимости в такой неограниченной гибкости в вашем коде, где вектор все равно жестко прописан как вектор `IAnimal *`. Я бы сказал, что вариант с `std::initializer_list` из ответа @Harry тут более уместен.

Comment: О, красивый способ :)

Comment: А как-то можно красиво на уровне объявления ограничить - что все arg в пакете - одного типа?

Comment: @Harry: Насколько я знаю - нет. Я так понимаю, что автор хотел иметь возможность передавать туда указатели на *разные* типы, хоть и все унаследованные от `IAnimal`. Просто в своем примере он этого не сделал. Можно потребовать, чтобы все были *указателями*,  объявив конструктор как `Farm(anyClass *... arg)`

Comment: Да, со специализацией понятно... А нет ли какого-то тогда хитрого fold expression, которое можно, скажем, в static_assert поместить?

Answer (score 1):

1. В вектор помещается вот так:

   ```
   (vec.push_back(arg), ...);
   ```
2. Память за собой очищать надо.
3. Отсутствие виртуального деструктора вызовет UB при удалении.

Код полностью (с исправлениями): https://ideone.com/tcbHKl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class IAnimal {
public:
  virtual ~IAnimal() {}
  virtual void fuu() = 0;
};

class Animal : public IAnimal {
public:
  Animal(){}
  void fuu(){}
};

template<class... anyClass> class Farm {
public:
  Farm(anyClass... arg) {
    (vec.push_back(arg), ...);
  }

private:
  std::vector<IAnimal*> vec;
};

int main() {
  IAnimal* dog = new Animal();
  IAnimal* cat = new Animal();

  Farm<IAnimal*, IAnimal*> obj(dog,cat);

  delete cat;
  delete dog;
}
```

Comment: Я сей час скажу ерунду, но у меня нет полей с данными. А если их нет, то откуда взяться утечке? Таблица виртуальных функций? А если бы скажем у меня не было интерфейса?

Comment: @Nik, но сам объект-то есть и указатель на что-то указывает.

Comment: Да, вы абсолютно правы.