# Шаблоны с переменным количеством аргументов - но одним параметром

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Навеяло этим [вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/922201/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-variadic-templates).

Итак, имеется какой-то шаблонный класс, в который мы хотим передать неизвестное заранее количество аргументов, но одного и того же типа.

Простейшее решение - передача через параметризованный `initializer_list`.

Но мы не ищем легких путей :) и хотим использовать шаблон с переменным количеством аргументов, но с единственным типом всех аргументов. И с вот таким ограничением.

Как выразить такое ограничение? Неважно - в рамках С++17 или С++20 (намекаю на концепты).

Comment: non-type parameter pack не подойдёт?

Comment: я вообше не понел, чем же вам не нравится простейшее  решение ?    И чем не подходят контейнеры?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Это не практическая задача. Мне не нужно это делать. Просто стало интересно, не более того.

Comment: @cppquestions Я так понял, параметры не обязательно `constexpr`.

Comment: Тогда можно так, например: template<class T, class... Tail>
struct are_same : std::bool_constant<(std::is_same_v<T, Tail> && ...)> {};

Comment: И потом SFINAE: template<typename... Args> std::enable_if_t<are_same<Args...>::value> foo(Args... args) {}

Comment: @cppquestions Ага, это уже неплохой вариант...

Comment: @Harry, может ты имеешь ввиду *function parameter pack* без всяких шаблонов: `Farm(IAnimal* animals...): vec{animals} {  }`

Comment: @Fat-Zer Нет, именно когда тип не фиксирован, т.е. представляет собой параметр типа шаблона, но он единственный для всех аргументов.

Comment: А шаблон должен сам определять общий тип аргументов? Или он будет указываться явно в `<>`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Как-то не задумывался. Ну, как вам удобнее.

Comment: @Harry, [тоже самое](https://paste.pound-python.org/show/84ibiAqKUp1H75A33x7p/), только заменить `IAnimal` на обычный шаблон, не?

Comment: @Fat-Zer Не работает. Вот, попробуйте - http://vpaste.net/OE2nw

Comment: @Harry, да не в ту сторону копал — думал это какой-то новый синтаксис, а оказалось просто запятая перед многоточием в старой доброй Сишной функции с переменным числом аргументов опциональна >_<

Comment: @Fat-Zer да, могу посоветовать [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/910860/317064) ответ

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов.

**(1)** Если тип аргументов либо известен заранее (возможно является параметром шаблона, который нужно задавать явно), тогда берем `std::is_convertible` и SFINAE.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename 

template <
    typename T,
    typename ...P,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<(std::is_convertible_v<P, T> && ...)>
>
void foo(P &&... params)
{
    auto print = [](auto &&x){std::cout << x << '\n';};
    (print(T(std::forward<P>(params))) , ...);
}

int main()
{
    foo<int>(1, 2.3, 3ll); // Печатает `1 2 3`.
}
```

В комментариях предложили `std::is_same`, но он менее удобен. С ним при передаче параметров иногда требовалось бы явно приводить типы: `foo<int>(1, int(2.3), int(3ll));`

Так как из-за `std::is_convertible` параметры могут оказаться разных (неявно приводимых к `T`) типов, может иметь смысл перед использованием приводить их к `T`, как в примере выше.

Если не нравятся (или не нужны в вашем случае) универсальные ссылки, естественно, можно использовать константные:
`void foo(const P &... params)`
Или вообще передавать под значению:
`void foo(P ... params)`
В этих случаях, `forward`, конечно, не нужен.

Если не нравится SFINAE, можно убрать последний шаблонный параметр и использовать что-то вроде
`static_assert((std::is_convertible_v<P, int> && ...), "Invalid argument types.");`

---

**(2)** Если общий тип аргументов заранее неизвестен, и вы хотите, чтобы компилятор определял его за вас, берем `std::common_type`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <
    typename ...P,
    typename T = std::common_type_t<P...>
>
void foo(P &&... params)
{
    auto print = [](auto &&x){std::cout << x << '\n';};
    (print(T(std::forward<P>(params))) , ...);
}

int main()
{
    foo(1, 2.3, 3ll); // `T` определяется как `double`, печатает `1 2.3 3`.
}
```

Обратите внимание, если компилятор не смог определить подходящий общий тип, на строке `typename T = std::common_type_t<P...>` сработает SFINAE.

Если вдруг хочется использовать `static_assert` вместо SFINAE, тогда нужно убрать `typename T` и использовать что-то вроде
`static_assert(std::experimental::is_detected_v<std::common_type_t, P...>, "Invalid argument types.");`
В этом случае для удобства можно добавить внутрь функции `using T = std::common_type_t<P...>;`. (И не забудьте `#include <experimental/type_traits>`.)

---

**(3)** Универсальный вариант. Самый удобный, но нужно больше шаблонного кода.

Можно либо задавать тип явно, либо оставить его определение компилятору.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename ...P>
using maybe_explicit_common_type_t = typename std::conditional_t<std::is_void_v<T>,
    std::common_type<P...>,
    std::enable_if<(std::is_convertible_v<P, T> && ...), T>
>::type;
// Используем старомодный `typename ... ::type` чтобы SFINAE вдруг
// неожиданно не сработал в отброшенной ветке.

template <
    typename RawT = void,
    typename ...P,
    typename T = maybe_explicit_common_type_t<RawT, P...>
>
void foo(P &&... params)
{    
    auto print = [](auto &&x){std::cout << x << '\n';};
    (print(T(std::forward<P>(params))) , ...);
}

int main()
{
    foo(1, 2.3, 3ll); // `T` определяется как `double`, печатает `1 2.3 3`.
    foo<int>(1, 2.3, 3ll); // Печатает `1 2 3`.
}
```

Тут тоже можно использовать `static_assert` на `std::experimental::is_detected`, как в варианте **(2)**.

Comment: Спасибо! Мозги загрузили капитально :)