# Узнать тип на этапе компиляции

Tags: c++

Можно ли определить тип переданных параметров `variadic templates`, на этапе компиляции?

Хочу использовать `static_assert` для проверки допустимости передачи параметра в шаблон.

Допустим запретить передачу в шаблон типа `float`

```
int main() {

    MyClass <int, double, int, char> obj; // так можно
    MyClass <double, char> obj;          // так тоже
    MyClass <int, float> obj;            // а вот так нельзя

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А как еще их можно определить, кроме как во время компиляции? 8-0

Comment: Не понял вопрос, можно подробнее? Вот пусть у вас есть `template <typename ...P>`, и вы какие-то типы передали в `P`. Что значит *"определить тип"*?

Comment: Вам что-то вроде вот этого нужно? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/922226/

Comment: @Nik уточните задачу, пожалуйста. В данной постановке непонятно какие утверждения должны быть проверены в staic_assert

Comment: При чем здесь "колличество" (sic), если в примере у вас, как будто, ограничение на *состав* типов (т.е. все можно, но нельзя float)

Comment: @AnT Да, я очень плох в объяснениях.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как уже ответил @AnT, в C++17 появились `fold expressions`.

Если использование C++17 недоступно, то можно сделать следующим образом:

```
template<typename ... Args>
struct any_of;    

template<typename CheckType, typename HeadType, typename ... Args>
struct any_of<CheckType, HeadType, Args...>: any_of<CheckType, Args...> {};    

template<typename CheckType, typename ... Args>
struct any_of<CheckType, CheckType, Args...>: std::true_type {};    

template<typename CheckType>
struct any_of<CheckType>: std::false_type {};

//использование
template<typename ... Args>
struct MyClass
{
    static_assert(!any_of<float, Args...>::value, "float not supported");
};

//...
MyClass<int, double> d1;//ok
MyClass<float, int> d2;//assertion
```

---

Для понимания работы этого кода предлагаю разобраться сначала с возможной реализацией `is_same` для двух типов:

```
//Общая версия шаблона наследуется от std::false_type,
//что дает сразу готовый член value и операцию преобразования к bool.
//false_type::value имеет значение false
template<typename T, typename U>
struct my_is_same: std::false_type
{};

//Весь "фокус" в данной специализации.
//Данная специализация будет выбрана, если типы переданные в шаблон одинаковые (T и T).
//И эта специализация наследуется от std::true_type, 
///и член value равен true
template<typename T>
struct my_is_same<T, T>: std::true_type
{};
//...
static_assert(my_is_same<float, float>::value, "failure"); //ок - my_is_same здесь наследник std::true_type
static_assert(my_is_same<float, int>::value, "failure"); //ошибка - my_is_same здесь наследник std::false_type
```

Думаю, прием с наследованием от `false_type` и `true_type` понятен.

В начальном коде используется еще один прием - наследование в шаблоне класса от самого себя с другим набором аргументов шаблона. Разберем и его на примере первоначального кода.

```
//Общая версия шаблона не реализуется и не используется
//Вместо нее будут использоваться специализации
template<typename ... Args>
struct any_of;

//Данная специализация выбирается если параметров более одного.
//any_of в данном случае наследуется от any_of, при этом отсекается параметр HeadType,
//т.е. он не передается в качестве аргумента шаблону базового класса.
//Таким образом с каждой "ступенью" наследования отсекается один тип из списка аргументов.
//при этом отсекается второй тип (HeadType), т.к. первый (CheckType) -
//это тот тип, который необходимо проверить.
template<typename CheckType, typename HeadType, typename ... Args>
struct any_of<CheckType, HeadType, Args...>: any_of<CheckType, Args...> {};

//Наследование и "отсечение" будет происходить до тех пор, 
//пока не упремся в одну из следующих специализаций:


//Эта специализация будет выбрана, если первый и второй параметры шаблона одинаковы.
//Здесь уже используется наследование от std::true_type, 
//что прерывает цепочку наследования от any_of,
//таким образом any_of становится наследником std::true_type, 
//если хоть один аргументов, переданных изначально в any_of, совпадает с первым аргументом.
template<typename CheckType, typename ... Args>
struct any_of<CheckType, CheckType, Args...>: std::true_type {};

//если же мы дошли до такого момента, когда остался только проверяемый тип,
//значит в списке аргументов any_of не было типов, совпадающих с первым,
//поэтому прерываем наследование от any_of наследованием от std::false_type.
template<typename CheckType>
struct any_of<CheckType>: std::false_type {};

//Таким образом, если в пакете Args... в any_of<Type, Args...> есть тип Type, 
//то any_of<Type, Args...> станет наследником std::true_type,
//в ином случае any_of<Type, Args...> станет наследником false_type

static_assert(any_of<float, int, float>::value, "float not supported");//ok - any_of наследник std::true_type
static_assert(any_of<float, int, double>::value, "float not supported");//ошибка - any_of наследник std::false_type
```

Comment: Если вам не сложно, не могли бы вы объяснить, что же тут происходит.

Comment: @Nik добавил объяснение.

Answer (score 3):

Для этого фактически и предназначены fold expressions в C++17

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... Args>
class MyClass
{
  static_assert(!(... || std::is_same_v<Args, float>));
};
```

Comment: Это лучшее решение. Но к сожалению С++17 для меня не доступен.

Comment: @Nik Это тоже желательно сразу писать в вопросе. Мы ж не экстрасенсы. :(

Answer (score 2):

Весь template type deduction работает именно на этапе компиляции. То есть, когда вы определяете объект шаблонного класса, компилятор скомпилирует используемый класс именно с подставленным типом в шаблонный параметр. Если вы по каким-то причинам хотите запретить пользователю использовать в качестве параметра какой-то определенный тип, то вы должны запретить конструктор для данного шаблона с таким параметром (типом). Пример :

```
 template <typename T>
 class Foo
 {
 public:
   T a;
 };

template<typename int>
class Foo
{
public:
 Foo() = delete;
};
```

Если вы попытаетесь создать объект `Foo<int>`, то компилятор выдаст ошибку. Отвечая на вторую часть вопроса про static_assert. В данном случае можно попробовать определить тип именно так

```
 static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(foo.a), bool>::value, "retval must be bool");
```

Принцип использования должен быть понятен

Comment: Да, это мне понятно, не понятно как использовать если у меня parameter pack. Например template<class... Any> class AnyClass;

Comment: @Nik тогда уточните вопрос, что именно вы хотите получить от этого parameter pack

Comment: Запретить некоторые типы для использования в шаблоне.